# R: merge two SpatialPolygonsDataFrames based on their polygons

Tags: r, merge, polygon, spatial

I have 2 SpatialPolygonsDataFrames (data1 and data2). The polygons represent buildings. data1 is all the buildings, data2 is some specific building.

I would like to add all the variables in data2@data to data1@data (for buildings which are in both SpatialPolygonsDataFrame).

I have looked for a way to aggregate or merge two SpatialPolygonsDataFrames by polygon, but I haven't found. Any idea?

## EDIT

To elaborate: I would like to join my two SpatialPolygonsDataFrames with the polygons has a key. I am absolutly not a specialist of spatial data objects, I have started to work on it this week.

Here what I have in my data:

```
colnames(data1@data)
[1] "id"         "nom_voie"   "id_fantoir" "numero"     "rep"        "code_insee" "code_post" 
 [8] "alias"      "nom_ld"     "x"          "y"          "commune"    "fant_voie"  "fant_ld" 

colnames(data2@data)
[1] "osm_id" "code"   "fclass" "name"   "type"
```

I would like to add the variables of data2 in data1 for polygons which are in bot SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. So after, my data1@data will be:

```
 [1] "id"         "nom_voie"   "id_fantoir" "numero"     "rep"        "code_insee" "code_post" 
 [8] "alias"      "nom_ld"     "x"          "y"          "commune"    "fant_voie"  "fant_ld"   
[15] "osm_id"     "code"       "fclass"     "name"       "type"
```

Comment: Is `sp::over()` what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello, I tried with over but it doesn't work due to a pb of data quality. Ultimatly, I computed the "center" of the shapes in dataset 1, checked in what shape it was in dataset 2 with over, then merge.